# running $.ajax with fancybox, cant close window on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

I am making a CMS for a website at the moment, and one of the features is that a the user can crop an image on the fly, they does this within a fancybox instance and all the details are possted to the controller via ajax, on successful cropping of the image, I am wanting to close the fancy box instance automatically, however I cannot seem to get the window to close, below is my code,

```
$("#crop").submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type    :   "POST",
        dataType:   "json",
        url     :   $(this).attr('action'),
        data    :   "x="+$("#x").val()+"&y="+$("#y").val()+"&x2="+$("#x2").val()+"&y2="+$("#y2").val()+"&w="+$("#w").val()+"&h="+$("#h").val()+"&isAjax=1&crop_image=Crop",
        success:function(json) {
            if(json.message == "Image Cropped") {
                $.fn.fancybox.close();
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Running this code works fine until `$.fancybox.close()` where I get this error,

> $.fn.fancybox.close is not a function

how can I close fancybox on a successful ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's:

```
$.fancybox.close();
```

- http://fancybox.net/faq

Comment: added `$.fancybox.close();` instead of `$.fn.fancybox.close()` no error but still a fancybox sitting over my content :(

Comment: Does this condition `if(json.message == "Image Cropped") {` evaluate to true? Can you output the value of `json.message` in your console/via alert?

Comment: `console.log(json.message)` returns Image Cropped, this return from within `IF` meaning that it must be true.

Comment: Just read this in the FAQ "Can the script be called from an iframe?","No".

Because the ajax request is happening in the iFrame does that mean I cannot close it from the ajax callback.

Comment: Ah, you did not mention anything about an iframe in your post.

Comment: Isn't that how fancybox works? By creating an iFrame and pulling the URL into that?

Comment: nope - by creating a DIV which is part of the markup of the very same page.